# Showing the user's username in registration email or activation page with BuddyPress

Tags: buddypress, user-registration, username

a) I would like the person's username to be included in their activation email once they have registered.

e.g. Activation email would look like:
Thanks for registering! To complete the activation of your account please click the following link and log in using *USERNAME* and password you chose:
*activation link url*

Or if that is not possible.

b) If it is easier to display it on the page once the activation link has been clicked in the email, I would like to show the person's username there.

e.g. Activation page:
Your account was activated successfully! You can now log in with the username *USERNAME* and password you provided when you signed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the username to the activation e-mail by adding this code either to the `bp-custom.php` or to the theme's `functions.php` file

```
add_filter('bp_core_signup_send_validation_email_message', 'add_username_to_activation_email',10,3);

function add_username_to_activation_email($msg, $u_id, $activation_url) {
    $username = $_POST['signup_username'];
    $msg .= sprintf( __("After successful activation, you can log in using your username (%1\$s) along with password you choose during registration process.", 'textdomain'), $username);
    return $msg;
}
```

**EDIT:** You are right, if the user used a space in his username, Buddypress will not show him an error and the registration process will continue. The next time user tries to log-in using his username with a space, the log-in process will fail. So we have to replace `$username = $_POST['signup_username']` as follows:

```
add_filter('bp_core_signup_send_validation_email_message', 'add_username_to_activation_email',10,3);

function add_username_to_activation_email($msg, $u_id, $activation_url) {
    // $username = $_POST['signup_username'];
    $userinfo = get_userdata($u_id);
    $username = $userinfo->user_login;
    $msg .= sprintf( __("After successful activation, you can log in using your username (%1\$s) along with password you choose during registration process.", 'textdomain'), $username);
    return $msg;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ahmad, that worked the first time I tried! The problem I'm having is that if a user signs up with the username Future Diamond, the email sends the username Future Diamond. But the correct login username to BuddyPress is Future-Diamond (a hyphen is added in place of the space). How do I get the email to show the hyphen?

Comment: The hyphen comes up now perfectly Ahmad, thank you.